# Attempting to pass values from GUI to another app with socket

Tags: python, sockets, user-interface, spi

As i state in the title i'm trying to create a 2 seperate applications, one being a GUI/client and the other being a controller/server.

The GUI uses several sliders to take an input from the user and transfers the value to the controller through a socket.

The controller receives the data and transfers it to another peripheral device, through a SPI connection.

The program transfers the first value and then proceeds to crash. The errors i get are these two :
error connection reset by peer and error broken pipe.

The gui code is

```
def Configure(e):
     
     Command(0, 0, ch0, reg_X, group_0, ch_0, 1)

def dacCommand(bus,dev,dacVar,command,dacGroup,dacChannel,multFac):



  Vref = 3
  offsetCode = 0x1555
  M = 65535
  C= 32768
  Iout=dacVar.get()
  Vout=Iout*multFac

  byte1 = command|dacGroup|dacChannel

  dacCode=math.ceil(Vout*(2**16)/(4*Vref)+4*offsetCode)
  inputCode=math.floor((dacCode-C+(2**15))*(2**16)/(M+1))

  d = struct.pack('<H', inputCode)
  data= [0, 0, 0 ]
  dataCommand = [byte1, d[1], d[0]]
  
  byte1bin=f'{byte1:08b}'
  byte2bin=f'{d[1]:08b}'
  byte3bin=f'{d[0]:08b}'
  
  dataString=byte1bin+byte2bin+byte3bin
  
  
  client_socket.send(bytes(dataString,"utf-8"))


if __name__ == "__main__":          

    window = Tk()
    window.title('DACs board control')
    window.geometry('1920x900')
   
    tab_control = ttk.Notebook(        window)
    
    tab2        =         Frame(  tab_control)
    tab_control.add(tab2, text= 'dev1 control')
    
    tab_control.pack(expand= 1,  fill= "both")
    
    ch0 = DoubleVar()
    ttk.Label(tab2, text= "ch0 (V)", font= ("Calibri", 12)).grid(column= 0, row= 0, padx= 10,     
    pady= 5)
    ch0Scale = Scale(tab2, from_= 0, to = Vmax, resolution = 0.05, state = "normal", variable= 
    ch0, command= Configure, font='Helevetica 11', length = 200, width = 15).grid(row = 1, 
    column = 0,  pady = 5, padx = 10, sticky = 'w')
    
    mainloop()
```

The controller code is :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":     
  spi=spidev.SpiDev()
  
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
  s.listen(5)
  
  conn, address = s.accept()
  print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")
  while True:
      
      
      command = conn.recv(24)
      if not command:
            break
      spi.open(0,0)
      spi.mode = 0b01
      spi.max_speed_hz = 1000000


      part1=command[:8]
      part2=command[8: 16]
      part3=command[16:]
      spi.xfer2([int(part1,2),int(part2,2),int(part3,2)])
      spi.close()
      
      
  conn.close()
```

Comment: They are doing a single operation, the server is waiting to rceive but the client doesnt send more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client and server are doing a single send and receive operation, to fix your problem you should make the client and server maintain the connection by a continuous communication.

first on the server side you should modify your code like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # ...

    while True:
        conn, address = s.accept()
        print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")
        
        while True:
            command = conn.recv(24)
            if not command:
                break
            
            # ...
        
        conn.close()
```

then on the client side:

```
from tkinter import filedialog

def Configure(e):
    # ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # ...
    window.createfilehandler(client_socket, tkinter.READABLE, Configure)

    # ...
    mainloop()
    window.deletefilehandler(client_socket)
```

it should work but you might have more issues because of `recv` you should look into asynchronous programming or multithreading.

Comment: Thanks guys! Used a combination of your recommendations and the programm worked !

Answer (score 1):

No need to send actual ones and zeros.  Send the bytes.  It appears you need to send the input code big-endian, so use `>` instead of `<` in the format string and include the command byte. Use `sendall` to ensure all 3 bytes are sent (very likely even with `send()` but `send()` can send less under the right conditions.

```
data = struct.pack('>BH', byte1, inputCode)
client_socket.sendall(data)
```

On the client, read the 3 bytes.  Note you should check the return value of `conn.recv` to make sure it actually receives 3 bytes.  The value is a *maximum* to receive.

```
data = conn.recv(3)
if len(data) != 3:
    # deal with it
spi.xfer2(list(data)) # list on bytes data will return the values,
                      # e.g., b'\x01\x02\x03' returns [1, 2, 3].
                      # May not be needed if the function accepts
                      # byte strings...
```